# what is skolem constant and logic variable?

Tags: logic

In logic I see skolem constant many times, it said it is used to substitute existential variable occurrences. but what is special about skolem constant and why we do such substitution, what is that skolem constant for? why not just leave existential variable alone?

another question is what is logic variable, what is that for?

could any one explain to me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One area where Skolem constants/functions are useful is in automated theorem proving using [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)). Resolution only works for formulas that don't contain existential quantifiers. This limitation can be resolved by *Skolemizing* the formula (i.e., replacing existential quantifiers with Skolem symbols).

Note that in general, if φ is a formula, then the Skolemized formula Sk(φ) is not logically equivalent to φ, that is, there may be structures in which one formula is true and the other false. But Skolemization *does* preserve satisfiability: φ is true in *some* model iff Sk(φ) is true in *some* model. For resolution, this is sufficient, equivalence is not necessary.

For the question about logic variables, you'll have to be more specific. In what context did you encounter logic variables?